# issues with six under django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use a package called vcrpy to accelerate the execution of my django application test suite. I'm using django 1.7 on Mac, with Python 2.7.

I added the following couple of lines to one of my tests:

```
import vcr
with vcr.use_cassette('recording.yaml'):
```

The result is an import error:

```
    import vcr
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vcr/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .config import VCR
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vcr/config.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .cassette import Cassette
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vcr/cassette.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .patch import CassettePatcherBuilder
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vcr/patch.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .stubs import VCRHTTPConnection, VCRHTTPSConnection
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vcr/stubs/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from six.moves.http_client import (
ImportError: No module named http_client
```

The problematic code in the VCR package itself is:

```
import six
from six.moves.http_client import (
    HTTPConnection,
    HTTPSConnection,
    HTTPMessage,
    HTTPResponse,
)
```

The funny thing: this code seems to run fine when I'm just running it from a plain python console, but it results in the above ImportError under Django or under the django manage.py shell.

Any idea what might be wrong?

( some additional details about the location of the six module:

When I'm running plain python console, I get the following:

```
Python 2.7.8 (v2.7.8:ee879c0ffa11, Jun 29 2014, 21:07:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import six
>>> print six.__file__
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.pyc
```

Doing the same thing, with `import django; django.setup()`, from `manage.py shell` results in exactly the same directory and same six.pyc file.

)

Comment: Can you add `import six; print six.__file__` somewhere in your code and tell us what that prints when running under Django? Does it match what is imported in the plain Python console?

Comment: So `from six.moves.http_client import HTTPConnection` works in the console, right? I do still suspect that a different `six` is being imported by the time you get to the `vcr.stubs` package. You could try and do the same print at the top of that `__init__` file where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Found your [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy/issues/131). The Django version also provides `six.moves.http_client`, so that shouldn't be an issue either.

Comment: Here's another funny thing. Even when I import the django version of six, I'm still getting the same error:
`
    from six.moves.http_client import HTTPConnection ...
    ImportError: No module named http_client
`

Comment: Six uses a [custom meta path importer](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/2828c8c72e975c326722c941c921b6f93498ea22/six.py?at=default#cl-162), so something is interfering with that then.

Comment: What does `sys.meta_path` look like by the time the failure happens?

Comment: Looking over the meta_path importer code, the two versions should not interfere.

Comment: when I print `sys.meta_path` from `manage.py shell` - either before or after importing six and / or django.utils.six, I get `[<six._SixMetaPathImporter object at 0x1062bded0>]`. In the regular python console, I have to import six first to get something into the meta-path.

Comment: I did `inspect.getfile(sys.meta_path[0].__class__)` from both `manage.py` and the regular python console. Got the same result: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.pyc`

Answer (score 9):

Maybe a little bit too late for the original question, but I came here trough Google so for future reference, here's my solution:

#### Problem

The problem I found is that mac os comes with not only python but also some packages pre-installed. Six is one of those packages and therein lies the conflict. The pre-installed six takes priority over the pip installed six, but pip still gives information based on what it itself has installed (e.g. six 1.9.0 vs 1.4.1).

pre-installed (version 1.4.1):

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/`

pip installed (whatever you have installed, for me it was 1.9.0):

`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`

You can check if this is the case for you by running:

```
$ python
>>> import six
>>> print six.__file__
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.py'
```

#### Fixing it

The solution is actually quite simple, just put

`export PYTHONPATH="/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"`

in your `~/.bashrc` (or whatever file your shell uses). If you've configured your pip to install somewhere else, put that in the pythonpath instead.

Comment: This helped me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Fedora 21. The reason for this was 2 installed version of the `six 1.2.0 and 1.9.0`. I solved this problem by the uninstall `six`, and re-installation latest version:

```
pip uninstall six
pip install six
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a multiple-versions conflict.  I solved a similar error by downgrading my version of six (1.9.0 caused the error, as did 1.8.0 and 1.7.0).  1.6.0 works without error.

The error I was getting:
from six.moves import http_client
ImportError: No module named moves